# Android Stack Memory Error(StackOverFlow)

Tags: android, stack, view, overflow

Good Day.Im having many nested layouts which i use to show views without killing my MainActivity view.(it is what Boss wants) after using them recursively i came to point where on back button of android pressed i must by idea go back to the another nested view,so again I'm calling recursively the view.Searching in internet i came to point that i can't increase the stack memory of android and that i get StackOverFlow error mainly because of heaps of nested views which more than Hierarchy can hold.My Question is how can i then go back to my another nested layout from completely different layout avoiding stackoverfowerror?(again my Boss wants all that so I'm short in functionality).Thank you very much beforehand!
Posting LogCat and piece of code which i use to add view.

Logcat

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13529)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3031)
        at android.widget.ListView.drawChild(ListView.java:3302)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2885)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2384)
        at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3297)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13824)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3881)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12742)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13529)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3031)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2885)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12740)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13529)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3031)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2885)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12740)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13529)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3031)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2885)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13824)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12742)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13529)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3031)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2885)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12740)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13529)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3031)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2885)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12740)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13529)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3031)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2885)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12740)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13529)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3031)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2885)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13824)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12742)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13529)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3031)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2885)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12740)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13529)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3031)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2885)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12740)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13529)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3031)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2885)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12740)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13529)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3031)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2885)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12740)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13529)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3031)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2885)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java
```

Code

```
context = Profile.this;
        activityManager = getLocalActivityManager();
        contentViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(switchlayout.getLayoutParams());
        nextActivit = new Intent(Profile.this, CardList.class);
        startGroupActivity("activity1", nextActivit);


  public void startGroupActivity(String id, Intent intent) {
    switchlayout.removeAllViews();
    View view = activityManager.startActivity(id, intent).getDecorView();
    switchlayout.addView(view, contentViewLayoutParams);

}
```

Comment: I found it funny when i read a question about stackoverflow in stackoverflow :D

Comment: haha what to do android is android:D

Comment: you can use fragment by the way and keep alive the activity

Comment: point is that If i use fragment it will not have its own activity but will be inflated,so android app going to be really slow and going to kill himself,thats why I'm using this method to have separate view with its own activity to handle android memory leaks though I'm leaking in stacks:D

Comment: its better if you put the layout and let us figure out how to optimize

Comment: still don't know why you can't use fragment

Comment: first of all fragments this or that way uses a code which its inside of,lets say Activity A have its own fragment Fragment A,so at this point Fragment A code must be written in Activity A in that point if i want to add heaps of images,functions i must to add in single java class which will reduce the functionality of android so I'm not using fragments

Answer (score 0):

I think you have this problem because you don't reuse the visible objects and you create new ones each time they become visible.
Take a look here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance on 8. ListViews and performance
You problem might be related to this.

Comment: no sorry not even this one..as its different i have more than 17 screens which must be separated and it must be completely different with functionality from others and by icons,drawables,views etc.so i can't reuse every visible object again and again as it have to be different..

Comment: the listview concept is different... have you used it?

Comment: yes i used list view in one screen,but problem is that as i said i have different screens with different functionality so i can't use concept of list view

Comment: Why you are not using different activities for your screens? and in those screens use as much predefined UI elements as possible. Also, use inflaters.

Comment: i do use different activities for my screens but problem is that the very first MAIN Activity must remain alive i mean it must be on ui view so user every time must see it..

Comment: Why don' t you use a service that will update the activities states?

Answer (score 0):

The only **PROPER** way to achive your goal is to use Fragment. Statement that:

> first of all fragments this or that way uses a code which its inside
>   of,lets say Activity A have its own fragment Fragment A,so at this
>   point Fragment A code must be written in Activity A

it not right. U r free to have a code inside Fragment. But thats not the main point. Having u said the above tell me the difference about your way? You have one activity and many views. Doesn't that mean you have all the code inside your Activity allready? So whats the difference?
If you want to call parent activity's method,lets say yerSmartMethod(), from Fragment u can do it as easy as

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).yerSmartMethod();
```

is it that hard? No. If you want to have a SAME code for different Fragments all you u have to do is to develop some parent Fragment with such methods and extend it in all your Fragments. You can even declare it abstract. Like:

```
public abstract class AbstractFragment extends Fragment{

    public void yerSmartMethod(){
       //if you still wish to use your Activity's method here:
       ((MainActivity)getActivity()).yerSmartMethod();
       // or u r free to code it
    }
}
```

Now the 1st fragment:

```
public class My1stFragment extends AbstractFragment {
    ...
    //somewhere in code u wanna call this method, its just:
    yerSmartMethod();
    ...
}
```

So you dont need to keep all the methods in MainActivity.
The only thing left here is to develop your own stack of fragments cuz if app goues bg then the Fragments stack will be lost. Its known AOS behavior. But its easy to implement your own stack which will survive like your MainActivity does.

Comment: oh hell no...one more interesting thing....IM STILL GETTING STACKOVERFLOW ERROR even with your 'solution' clever guy

Comment: Are you following 1 fragment = 1 view schema? Or you are trying to swap views inside one frgament now? If you are using 2nd way is obviuos you gonna get the same SOE

Comment: swapping views surely,but before swap surely i do 'my view.removeAllViews()'

Comment: U r using fragments in a wrong way. You sould swap fragments (every with its own view) instead of swapping views inside one fragment. One your view == one fragment. Got it? Do not remove/swap views. Swap fragments.

Comment: hm ok yeah i know i have to do tat but problem is that the PRICK boss wants that..like i know that hierarchy mostly as i know 17 views can handle and even with android 4.4.2 which stack size is 18kb as i remember it will still give stack overflow error..but i can't understand one thing..if i have different screens and I'm swapping inside that different screens with new activities and removing views...how its possible that android still keeps nested views on stack??shouldnt android remove it from stack and add new view?

Comment: Well I can't see the whole source to say anything (maybe you have some references which keeps removed views in RAM). Try fragments way or try to create an activity for your every view (loading layout in onCreate()). Just to ensure that won't throw an SOE after switching all the views (fragments/activities). And let us know about.